# How long to wait before cleaning new tuckpointed brick mortar with muriatic acid?

Tags: cleaning, brick, masonry

I am about to retuckpoint my exposed brick wall with a custom mortar mix (1x hydraulic lime, 2.5x sand).  Once I am done, I plan to clean the residue and other dirt from the bricks using muriatic acid.

My question is: what is the minimum amount of time I should wait for the mortar to cure before it is safe to apply muriatic acid over it?  Is a couple of days enough?  I have heard that masonry mixes (concrete/mortar) take as long as two weeks to fully cure, I was unsure whether it is safe to bring it in touch with a substance as potent as muriatic acid during that time frame.

Comment: Curious about the lime mortar..  is it a NHL based?  Do you have old, soft bricks or some other reason for using a lime mortar outside?

Comment: yes, the house (and its bricks) are 104 yrs old.  also, i think the lime-based mortar (white) looks better.  also, it is inside, not outside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would scrub with water only @10hrs - 48 hrs.

I wouldn't use muriatic/water until 3-4 weeks. Be sure to add acid to water, not water to acid.  An 8:1 (water-acid) mix is a good place to start.

Pre-wet the wall and any plants nearby. Rinse off then neutralize with ammonia or baking soda and water.

Old clothes, rubber gloves, eye protection.  If you use it any more concentrated, organic respirator.

Comment: i have added water to acid before and had no problem.  why do you say the opposite?

Comment: Small amounts of water (into acid) could potentially boil, spraying a (mostly) acid solution.

Answer (score 0):

that answer is not truly accurateit depends on the weather you're having that Day if it is really hoT it will dry extremely fastso what I recommend is use a paint brush just a bit and Muriatic acid on brick then wipe off immediately With water then take a hose and clean acid off the structure let dry for about a good 24 hours the spray a water sealer over structure to protected from elements